# What is the capacity of evopdf?

Tags: specifications, capacity, evopdf

How much volume can the EVO HTML to PDF Converter for .net handle?
What specs do you recommend for the server?

I am unable to find information regarding this matter on evopdf.com.

Comment: Support@evopdf.com isn't answering my inquiries either.

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies in chapter 3 of the the [EVO HTML to PDF user guide](http://www.evopdf.com/userguide/UserGuide.htm#Requirements), see the excerpt below.

## 3. Requirements and Recommendations

The recommended hardware and software resources for successfully running the EVO HTML to PDF converter for .NET are listed below. Basically this is the environment we used for testing the product.

- Operating System: Windows XP, Windows 2003 Server, Windows Vista, Windows Server 2008, Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows 8, Windows Server 2012
- Hardware Architecture: 32-bit, 64-bit (recommended to run the converter in a 64-bit process)
- Free RAM: 2GB
- Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0 or 4.0
- Full trust level when used in ASP.NET applications

Comment: How much volume can the EVO HTML to PDF Converter for .net handle?

Comment: Besides the fact that you can run the library in parallel AFAIK, it's hard to point out a volume. It depends on the HTML DOM size, the quality of the PDF (or images) to render and much more variables. Perhaps you could try it out and post back results?

Comment: For posterity's sake, it's worth mentioning that there is a concurrency setting that defaults to 4. Or in other words, you won't be creating more than four documents in parallel, until you tweak that (static) property.

EvoPdf.HtmlToPdfConverter.PdfConverterConcurrencyLevel